# How to reduce the nesting of these if-conditionals?

Tags: objective-c, logic, conditional-statements

i have a little problem :D
i can't find the right words for searching so i wrote this question.
how i get this shorter? I know with this logic || but how i could add more than 1 in one line?
Thanks for time
Best regards
John

```
    bool b = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Input"];
    if (b ==true)
    {
           bool b = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Output"]; 
           if (b ==true)
           {
                     bool b = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"statecheck"]; 
                     if (b ==true)
                     {
                     ....
                     }
           }
     }
```

Comment: What is this `NSStringContains:contains:` thing?  That is an awful method name;  why not just use the existing string methods directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you seem to need `&&`:

```
if ([self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Input"] &&
    [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Output"] &&
    [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"statecheck"])
{
   ...
}
```

For what it's worth, given `bool b;`, `if (b==true)` is always redundant -- just use `if (b)`.

Comment: How i code this, when only one condition from this 3 Statements must be right to go into?

Comment: @John: I'm not sure quite what you're asking. Do you mean you want something like `if (..."Input") xxx else if (..."Output) yyy else if (..."statecheck") zzz;` ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this:

```
bool hasInput = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Input"];
bool hasOutput = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"Output"];
bool hasStatecheck = [self NSStringContains:convert contains:@"statecheck"];
if (hasInput && hasOutput && hasStatecheck)
{
}
```

What you are using is, "if this condition, then check this condition, and this condition", etc. You can put these together with a logical AND, denoted by the `&&`.

Comment: Isnt it wasting steps? if the first is false you dont need to check the next cases.  When the first condition fails in ( x && y && z) then the rest wont be checked and save the two steps of operations

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW That's true, in that kind of performance is needed then Jerry's solution is better. I would write the code to be readable first.

Comment: Exactly. I'd write it like this before, and in the unusual case that this proves to be a performance bottleneck, rewrite without the variables.